# Making accordions with tabs in asp.net using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

Im making accordion tabs using jquery in visual studio and the panes don't expand or collapse at the moment. I'm getting this error 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tabs' 
Here is my html

```
<section id="Popularquestions">
            <h4>Popular Questions</h4>
        <h5 class="current">1.What are the most common camera ports?</h5>
        <div class="pane"><p><a href="Knowledgebase/commonports.aspx">Here</a> is a table of the most common camera ports available</p></div>
        <h5>2.Where can I see a list of vendors and their MAC addresses?</h5>
        <div class="pane"><p></p></div>
        <h5>3.Where can I see a list of makes and models?</h5>
        <div class="pane"><p></p></div>
        <h5>4.Where can I see a list of usernames and passwords?</h5>
        <div class="pane"><p></p></div>
        <h5>5.Where can I see a list of available apps?</h5>
        <div class="pane"><p></p></div>
```

jquery

```
<script src="assets/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#accordion").tabs(
    "#accordion div.pane",
    { tabs: 'h2', effect: 'slide', initialIndex: null }
  );
    </script>
```

And css

```
#accordion {
    background:#333 url(/media/img/gradient/h300.png) 0 0;
    width: 300px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    -background:#666;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* accordion header */
#accordion h2 {
    background:#ccc url(/media/img/gradient/h30.png);
    line-height: 14px;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px 15px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* currently active header */
#accordion h2.current {
    cursor:default;
    background-color:#fff;
}

/* accordion pane */
#accordion .pane {
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-width:0 2px;
    display:none;
    height:180px;
    padding:15px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:12px;
}

/* a title inside pane */
#accordion .pane h3 {
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#999;
}
```

Comment: Where is the div with id='accordion'?

Comment: intellisense doesn't recognise the .tabs part of the method so am I missing something there?

Comment: I just added that it makes no difference apart from css, same error is there

Comment: are you using jquery ui tabs? if yes, did you forget to include jqueryui library?

Comment: Head on over to http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ and make sure that you click on the view source link to see how the html is structured and the javascript files that are required.

Comment: I added the jquery ui but I have this error now                             Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method '#accordion div.pane'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
 <script>
$(function() {

 $("#accordion").tabs(
    "#accordion div.pane",
    { tabs: 'h2', effect: 'slide', initialIndex: null }

});
</script>
```